# Can't find the mistaks in my program

Tags: python

I have the following, but keep getting the TypeError: 'Item' object is not iterable. Can anyone help me?

```
import xlrd

class Item (object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def readItems(self):
        wb = xlrd.open_workbook("data3.xls")
        sh = wb.sheet_by_index(0)
        sh1 = wb.sheet_by_index(1)
        for i in range(1, sh.nrows):
            item = Item()
            item.matNumber = sh1.row_values(i)[0]

class System(Item):

def __init__(self):
        self.item = item

    def ABC(self):
        for i in self.item:
            print item.matNumber

item = Item()            
system = System()

system.ABC()
```

Comment: The error message seems clear. `Item` does not provide any interface that makes it iterable. What do you expect `i` to be in `for i in self.item`? Also, you better pass `item` as argument to the `System` construcor. If you want to make `Item` iterable, have a look at the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html#iterators).

Answer (score 1):

You define self.item as one item. If you then use the for loop for that single item it is not iteratable.

You should make an items list and append to it in the first for loop and use then items to iterate through it.